# Cleric's Aligment Changes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric, alignment

There is an neutral cleric, Maximus, who is worshiping not a deity, but a cause; he's got two domains, War and Travel. At first level, he chose that he'll channel positive energy and will turn undead.

Then, his alignment became evil. As he doesn't worship a particular deity and his domains have nothing to do with alignments, I believe he still has access to his divine magic AND both domains, but the real question is: What happens to his channel energy ability, as well as his turning ability?

Does he still possess the positive energy abilities, or do both of them turn into "negative energy" and "rebuke undead"?

Comment: Interesting question, added alignment tag as well for you ;)

Comment: If the cleric isn't worshiping a deity, from where does he get the divine magic?

Comment: If the cleric is switching between multiple, that's a bit of a rigmarole: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21286/are-there-any-rules-for-a-cleric-to-change-his-faith

Answer (score 13):

From the Player's Handbook, pg33:

> A good cleric (or a neutral cleric who worships a good deity) can turn or destroy undead creatures. An evil cleric (or a neutral cleric who worships an evil deity) instead rebukes or commands such creatures, forcing them to cower in awe of his power. If your character is a neutral cleric of a neutral deity, you must choose whether his turning ability functions as that of a good cleric or an evil cleric. Once you make this choice, it cannot be reversed. This decision also determines whether the cleric cast spontaneous *cure* or *inflict* spells (see above).

It says evil clerics rebuke undead and spontaneously cast *inflict* spells. While it does say that neutral clerics who pick one or the other can't change their mind, it does **not** say that your abilities don't change when you change alignments.

To borrow a computer science term, it's stateless: it doesn't care about what your alignment was in the past, only what your alignment is **now**. If the cleric is evil right now, he rebukes undead and spontaneously casts *inflict* spells. If he doesn't like that, he needs to move back to neutral and then choose turning undead & spontaneous *cure* casting (note that this choice *does* have state: the rules says it cannot be reversed, so any time he moves from good/evil to neutral, he uses whatever he picked the *first* time he was neutral).

Comment: Okay, so it's more like "Damn, I'm casting turns again! Gotta go kick up some kiddos before I may get back to my laundry!"... Fascinating 8)

Comment: The "Once you make this choice, it cannot be reversed" part makes me think that once you've chosen which way you swing while Neutral, you can't reverse that.  So if you choose to act as an evil cleric while neutral, you'll have to get all the way to good before you start with turns, and if you drop to neutral afterward you'll go back to rebukes.

Answer (score 1):

Most DMs I know make so that if a cleric changes their alignment, their deity forsakes them until they Attone (something like the Paladin).  This means that until they are redeemed or find a new deity to take them in, they get no spells since there's no divine fuel in the tank.

Again going with personal circles, the deity makes the power over the dead.  Being under a good deity almost always means a good cleric, and the inverse is often true as well.  If your alignment and deity match up, then the turning/rebuking should match.

Comment: My experiences as both player and DM are different.  If you move to an *incompatible* alignment, the deity will forsake them until they atone.  But the alignment doesn't have to be a perfect match between cleric and deity and the cleric's alignment can move around within the compatible zone.

Comment: Usually players in my circles are good about their alignments, but the DMs take the magic very seriously because of how quickly it can be abused.